# Google Chrome starts on a Virtual Machine on Ubuntu 20.04 per default as incognito, how to change that?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, chrome

I have two virtual machines and on one it does start in incognito mode per default and on the other it does not.

There is not a thing that i installed differently as far as i can remember.

**What could be reasons for that or how could i change that?**

Is there maybe a chrome settings file where something like 'incognito_on_start = true' is written?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is started by using a `--incognito` parameter in the command. So check the corresponding `.desktop` file (your desktop manager likely has a way to edit commands in the start menu).